# Static block not showing in left column of CMS page

Tags: cms, static-block

I have a CMS page with Page layout of '2 columns with left bar'.  I'd like to display a static block within the left column of this page, however, i'm running into some difficulties.

In the Layout Update XML I'm inserting the following code:

This does not show up:

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_badges">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_thing_badges</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

This, however, does:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_badges">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_thing_badges</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I tested it with `<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>` and it's working fine. Are you sure that you are using template with left column. Please activate **Template Path Hints** and **Add Block Names to Hints** and check.

Comment: @michael I turned on template path hints and add block names to hints and the Mage_Page_Block_Html is set to .../default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml

Comment: Did you check the layout files? Maybe the `cms_badges` block is removed from the `left` block somewhere in there. You could try changing the block name.